# Fixing UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

```
def main():
    cash = float(input("How much money: "))
    coins = 0

def changeCounter(n):
    while True:
        if cash - n > 0:
            cash -= n
            coins += 1
        else:
            break
    return

main()
changeCounter(0.25)
```

When I run this code, I get the error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cash' referenced before assignment

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variables `cash` and `coins` live only in the "scope" of function `main`, i.e. are not visible in `changeCounter`. Try:

```
def main():
    cash = float(input("How much money: "))
    coins = 0
    return cash, coins

def changeCounter(n, cash, coins):
    while True:
        if cash - n > 0:
            cash -= n
            coins += 1
        else:
            break
    # return
    return coins # presumably

cash, coins = main()
changeCounter(0.25, cash, coins)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `cash` and `coins` as [global variable](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python):

```
cash = 0
coins = 0

def main():
    global cash, coins

    cash = float(input("How much money: "))
    coins = 0

def changeCounter(n):
    global cash, coins

    while True:
        if cash - n > 0:
            cash -= n
            coins += 1
        else:
            break
    return

main()
changeCounter(0.25)
```

> But better way than storing the state in global variables is using
>   returing variables and function arguments or other method. See
>   [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

Comment: You need make `coins` global too then.

Comment: If you are keeping cash as global then you should keep coins as global too.